# How can I edit a row in a 7GB csv file?

Tags: text-processing, emacs, editors

I have a .csv file which is 7+ GB and has 30M rows.
When I load the file into a database table in SQL Server, it reports the position of a row  with some format problem, probably due to some fields missing.

I can see the row with the position (i.e. row number), by using less

```
less +24923786 -N huge.csv
```

I try to open it in Emacs, but it is too big for Emacs to open. Is it normal? (I am actually using `less` in git bash, and portable Emacs in Windows. So I don't know if full fledged Emacs can open it and allow me to edit the row.)

How can I edit the row in the csv file? (I am interested in a tool in Linux, or some editor available in git bash, or having a portable version for Windows)

Thanks.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "edit". Do you mean open in a text editor, or will applying a regexp replacement (with say `sed`) suffice?

Comment: I just want to have `,,` for each missing field in that row. If you have a sed command to do that, that will be great. I hope it is available in git bash or has some portable version in Windows.

Comment: Emacs has to my understanding some assumptions on its data structures that makes it slow for large files.  If you have a 64-bit vim it should be able to edit it (but might need ekstra disk space).

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen what is the limitation on the files which emacs can open (and edit)? I am not a vim user.

Comment: Googling for "emacs file size" found https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Problems-with-very-large-files.html so this might be a thing of the past even though you were warned.

Comment: I feel like this is a good illustration of why ambiguously parseable formats like CSV aren't sensible for exchange of large datasets. Anyway, wouldn't it be more sensible to set up your CSV parser in a way that definitely understands all rows correctly? If the thing goes visibly wrong on line 24923786, how much trust do you really have that there's no data ending up in the wrong columns on the other lines? This question reads like you have a big red flashing warning light and are trying to find the most elegant way of draping a blanket over it, so that it doesn't distract you as much.

Comment: Regarding `I just want to have ,, for each missing field in that row.` - [edit] your question to describe how a tool could know which field(s) are missing and provide sample input/output. Once you can describe the edit, you should be able to just tell sed or awk to make that change to that line. You will need an extra 7+G of storage of course.

Comment: If you're willing to consider a Perl-family language (i.e. Raku), see: ["Reading files can't be this simple"](https://conf.raku.org/talk/158); with [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/util/reading-files-cant-be-this-simple).

Answer (score 4):

`ed` could edit a single line very easily. `c` is the command to change (replace) a line; the period on a line by itself is the signal that you're done adding text; `wq` writes the changed file back to disk and quits ed:

```bash
$ ed huge.csv
24923786c
new,data,goes,here
.
wq
```

Or as a bash "one"-liner:

```bash
$ ed -s huge.csv <<< $'24923786c
new,data,goes,here
.
wq
'
```

Comment: The problem with this is that `ed` reads the whole file into memory. It would be better if the file could be edited in `sed` with e.g. `sed '24923786 s/something/other/'` or with a `c` command or what's needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to actually edit the singular line in an editor you could use `sed` like this to extract line, edit then splice back in (supposing a compatible version or sed is in git-bash - it should be):

```
sed '24923786,24923786p' -n huge.csv  > line.txt
edit line.txt
sed '24923786,24923786{s/.*/cat line.txt/e;}' -i huge.csv
```

Please test first and take a backup (you can use suffix argument to `i` option like `-i.bak` to have sed automatically make a backup of the original file to `huge.csv.bak`).

---

Aside: I'd be surprised if there wasn't some editor out there that had specific support for this - opening and allowing editing of a range of lines in huge text file - but I'm not aware of it. All I know is gedit (my goto editor) crashes badly with slightly largish files and vscode seems to do a lot better, but haven't had to deal with it beyond that lately.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a gawk command equivalent to that?

Comment: Nah I hate awk. sed isn't in git-bash?

Comment: both are in git bash. I used gawk more than sed.

Comment: `sed -i` makes a copy of the file, then shuffles the name. So whatever you do will need another 7GB and a full copy. I would use `head` and `tail | head` to split the file into 3 files A B C, lines `1..n-1`, line `n`, and lines `n+1..end`. Fix the single bad line by hand, then append files B and C to A. As your `n` is 25M out of 30M, B and C are relatively small.

Comment: A thought about the size of the A section of the file. You could use `tail +n` to slice off copies of the B and C parts first. Then get their sizes from `ls -l`, and shorten file A with `truncate --size=-nnn`. Then append the fixed B, and C, to A. That avoids copying the first 25M lines of the original.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant - yup, that'd be the right way to do it. Though I'd use other tools to get the lines and sizes eg. `num=24923786; A=$(( $(wc -c <infile) - $({ sed $(( num - 1 ))q | wc -c; sed -n -e '1w B' -e '1!w C'; } <infile) )); truncate -s -$A infile` then edit `B` in the editor and then `cat B C >>infile`

Comment: Your always going to have to split the file at some arbitrary N. The size of the first part  - which can truncate the original file to inplace - determines how much extra disk you need. Unless you conditionally `tac` the file online somehow before hand (which seems over the top for 7G), in the worst case you still end up needing an extra ~7G of tmp disk.